# Trouble getting a specific field from OpenWeatherMap API's output, via JS / XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, concatenation, openweathermap

So I'm building this web forecast app using OpenWeatherMap API, and so far I'm being able to fetch the data from the first iteration of the list's output, however I need to obtain the data of other specific fields aswell. Here's a bit of my code:

```
ajaxGet("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=4.6097&lon=-74.0817&exclude=current,minutely,hourly,alerts&appid=APPID&units=metric", function (response) {

      var data = JSON.parse(response);
      console.log(data);
      
      var temperature = document.createElement("h6");
      temperature.textContent = data.daily[0].temp.max + "°" + " / " + data.daily[0].temp.min + "°";

      document.getElementById("temperaturaBogVier").appendChild(temperature);
  });
```

And here's an example of what the API's output looks like (I'm only showing the first iteration in here, but there are at least 6 in total, https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=4.6097&lon=-74.0817&exclude=current,minutely,hourly,alerts&appid=APPID&units=metric):

```
{"lat":4.61,"lon":-74.08,"timezone":"America/Bogota","timezone_offset":-18000,"daily":
[
    
{"dt":1600876800,
 "sunrise":1600857917,
 "sunset":1600901504,
 "temp":{"day":18.14,"min":8.99,"max":18.14,"night":12.08,"eve":15.45,"morn":8.99},
 "feels_like":{"day":17,"night":11.02,"eve":14.6,"morn":7.58},
 "pressure":1017,"humidity":54,
 "dew_point":8.69,
 "wind_speed":1.2,
 "wind_deg":164,
 "weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10d"}],
 "clouds":82,
 "pop":0.94,
 "rain":5.85,
 "uvi":15.14}

]
}
```

So as you can see, I'm being able to print into my HTML the data contained into "data.daily[0].temp.", but it only works for the first set of fields and I got no clue how to select a specific iteration. I'm sure I'm missing something into the concat, but nothing I've tried has worked so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and rewarded with an imaginary waffle. THX :D

Comment: Do you mean like `data.daily[1]`, `data.daily[2]`, etc.? Or what do you mean with a specific iteration?

Comment: @DMalan Well, the output has an array in data.daily[0] that contains only one list, so there are no data.daily[1], data.daily[2] etc.. I'm trying to get a hold on the elements contained into this list, but since it is not an array on itself, I'm not very sure how to do so... ty for your reply btw

Comment: You might consider removing or replacing the `appid=XXXX` part of the request URL. This is your personal API key for OpenWeather, which you should not share.

Comment: @DiegoP. `data.daily[0] ` is an object and `data.daily` is an array that you can index with `data.daily[1]`, `data.daily[2]`, etc.

Comment: @DMalan thanks, you were totally right. I was calling only one row so that's why I wasn't able to fetch the rest of the information. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temperatures for each day `data.daily` are defined as an JavaScript array of objects. You can simply access them by their index, which indicates their position in the array.

```
data.daily[0] // First element
data.daily[1] // Second element
data.daily[2] // Third element
```

Once you have selected an object within the array, you can then access certain values like `data.daily[2].temp.max`.

The cool thing about arrays is that you can iterate them with a loop. This will save you a lot of writing, if you want to print out each temperatures for every day:

```
ajaxGet("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=4.6097&lon=-74.0817&exclude=current,minutely,hourly,alerts&appid=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&units=metric", function (response) {

  var data = JSON.parse(response);
  console.log(data);

  data.daily.forEach(function (date) {
    var temperature = document.createElement("h6");
    temperature.textContent = date.temp.max + "°" + " / " + date.temp.min + "°";

    document.getElementById("temperaturaBogVier").appendChild(temperature);
  })
});
```

**Please note:** I've removed the `appid=XXXXX` part of the request URL, because it contains your personal API key for OpenWeather, which you should not share publicly.

Comment: Ty very much for your explanation, I was handling the array wrongly. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to take all daily max/min-values and put them into elements that you want to append to another element.

Here is a way to do that

```
ajaxGet("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=4.6097&lon=-74.0817&exclude=current,minutely,hourly,alerts&units=metric", function (response) {
    var data = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(data);

    data.daily
        .map(datapoint => datapoint.temp) //get the temp value/object from each datapoint
        .map(temp => { //create an element and add each max/min value to that element's textContent
            const temperature = document.createElement("h6");
            temperature.textContent = temp.max + "° / " + temp.min + "°";
            return temperature;
        })
        .forEach(element => { //add each of the elements created in the previous map to the desired element
            document.getElementById("temperaturaBogVier").appendChild(element);
        });
});
```

As pointed out in the other answer, I've also removed the app-id query parameter